# Why aren't there cutting-edge compiler backends in functional languages like Haskell?

Tags: compiler-construction, haskell, functional-programming

current state-of-the-art compiler backends are mostly written in C/C++, the best example is possibly the LLVM infrastructure. Furthermore it is often stated that it would be nice to have some kind of a killer project implemented in a functional language.

Functional programming claims to have the advantage of solving heavily algorithmic problems in an elegant (and nowadays fast) way - compared to imperative languages. Nevertheless most compiler-backends are implemented in C/C++. I do know of the existence of, e.g. MLRisc but it seems outdated.

Thanks for hopefully lightning answers. For me a full compiler tool chain would be a real proof of the maturity of a language.

best regards,
uli

Comment: Why? Well, because either nobody made the effort, or the person who did didn't bring their result to your attention.

Comment: The state-of-the-art Haskell compiler [GHC](http://haskell.org/ghc/) is implemented in Haskell. AFAIK only parts of the runtime are written in C.

Comment: There are excellent LLVM bindings for Haskell. They look like the whole stuff was written as native Haskell.

Comment: @Alexandre C: AFAIK, GHC is one of the best compilers around. It seems to be, that there is kind of a "language shootout", where Haskell often gets good ranks.

Comment: State of the art compiler backends is a *very small* field - if you are discounting ML-RISC so quickly, can you actually name another one rather than LLVM? I can throw in the CoSY compiler suite, plus Microsoft had the Phoenix compiler suite a few years ago (maybe they now call it something else now?). LLVM, CoSY and Phoenix all target C / C++ - it's perhaps a lot to expect for industrial sponsored teams to develop a C/C++ compiler in a third language (i.e Haskell or ML).

Comment: Why is this closed? CW maybe, but not closed!

Comment: MLton and SML/NJ are both, I believe, written in SML. Both (and especially MLton with its whole-program optimization) are known for being quite efficient.

Comment: I don't think questions of the form "Why haven't unspecified people performed task X" are really sensible for SO.

Comment: This question would be better suited for open-ended discussion at [/r/haskell](http://reddit.com/r/haskell)

Comment: Maybe if the question was phrased a bit more curiously it wouldn't have been so readily closed. For example "what is the state of the art in compiler backends for functional languages, and who is working on them?"

Answer (score 9):

The probably most cutting-edge compiler both written in and for functional languages is probably GHC. It compiles Haskell and is - apart from the runtime system completely written in Haskell. I read about some compiler shootouts (sadly, I cannot find the source anymore), where Haskell took the third place, just after C and C++. It's really a pretty cool project.

GHC supports various target architectures, including x86 and x64, SPARK, and some others. GHC was ported to various platforms, including Linux, Windows, Mac OS X and various flavours of BSD. GHC can either directly emit assembly, or can use the LLVM backend to use the powerful LLVM optimizer. Additionally, there is a C backend, but it is to be removed in the next release.

Comment: GHC also supports a LLVM backend http://blog.llvm.org/2010/05/glasgow-haskell-compiler-and-llvm.html

Comment: I guess you're referring to [The Computer Language Benchmarks Game](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/which-programming-languages-are-fastest.php). The benchmark set was changed, so GHC isn't third place anymore, but it's still very competitive.